# Bitwise operations, confused with expression used in "The C programming Language"(book)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

In the book I am reading to learn C "The C programming language" in chapter 2.
The book is explaining Bitwise operations and it has a function that shows how many bits are in an integer.
The following is the function...

```
int Bitcount(unsigned x){

    int b;
    for(b = 0; x != 0; x >>=1){
      if(x & 01){
    b++
   }
 }
 return b;
}
```

Then an exercise is given to us stating exactly this.
"In a two's complement number system, x &= (x-1) deletes the rightmost 1-bit in x;
Explain why. Use this observation to write a faster version of Bitcount".

The problem is I really cannot understand how "x &= (x-1)" would work? can someone explain this to me? or send me to a resource that could better help me understand?
I have been trying to figure this out but I really can't.

Thank you for any help that you may give.
also if there is anything wrong with my question this is my first post so please help me make my questions better.

Comment: Sorry but how do I close this question because it has been answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X and X-1 cannot both have their rightmost bit set to 1, because in the binary system numbers ending in 0 and 1 alternate - so X & (X-1) is guaranteed to be a number whose rightmost bit set to 0 as AND only evaluates to true if both terms are true.  Maybe the confusion stems from what Andrew W said, here a bitwise AND is used (which ANDs each bit individually)?

EDIT: now, as Inspired points out, this is only part of the answer as the original problem specifies that the rightmost 1-bit will get reset.  As Andrew W already answered the correct version in detail, I'm not going to repeat his explanation here but I refer to his answer.

Comment: Thank you this makes it alot clearer I understand it alot more cheers :D

Comment: The question was not how it resets the rightmost bit, but how it resets the right-most ONE-bit.

Comment: You're welcome.  Even in these modern days concepts based on bitwise operations remain pretty important, spending some time on them is a good investment.  A good set of sometimes very nifty binary operations can be found on the [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) page, a definite must for every serious programmer :-)

Comment: @Inspired ah, I overread that part... and although it can be considered a generalization of what I said, it definitely makes Andrew's answer "more correct" than mine.  Thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 3):

It is equivalent to `x = x & (x-1)`  Here, the & is a bitwise and, not a logical and.

So here's what happens:

1)  The expression on the right will be evaluated first, and that value will be stored in x.

2)  Suppose `x = 01001011` in binary (this isn't the case, since more than 8 bits will be used to represent x, but pretend it is for this example).  Then `x-1 = 01001010`.

3)  compute the bitwise and:

```
01001011 &
01001010 =
01001010
```

which deleted the rightmost one bit.

now suppose number didn't end with a 1 bit:

Say: `x = 01001100`, the `(x-1) = 01001011`

compute the bitwise and:

```
01001100 &
01001011 =
01001000
```

again removing the rightmost 1.

Good book by the way.  I hope you enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a closer look at the rightmost 1 bit in x: suppose `x = AAAAAA10000..0`, where AAAAAA are arbitrary bits. Then `x-1 = AAAAAA01111..1`. Bitwise AND of these two expressions gives `AAAAAA00000..0`. This is how it resets the rightmost non-zero bit.

Comment: ok I sort of get it now combining this with fvu's comments thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is I really cannot understand how "x &= (x-1)" would work?

[Binary number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) is positional the same way as decimal number. When we [increase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Addition) the number we carry a bit to the left, when we decrease we borrow from the left the same way we do with decimals. So in case `x-01` we borrow the first 1-bit from the right while others being set to 1-bit:

```
     10101000
   - 00000001
     --------
     10100111
```

which is inversion of those bits till the first 1-bit. And as stated before by others `~y & y = 0` that is why this method can be used to count 1-bits as proposed by the book to make the method faster comparing to bits shifting.